# How should the second vowel in ציצת be pronounced?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

I presume that there a distinction in the way that different Chirik's are pronounced if they are blended syllables ("Chaser") or not ("Malei").  If so...

How should the word Tzitzis ציצת be pronounced? 
If the word is צִיצִת, wouldn't the second chirik be pronounced as a shorter sound, as in the word "מִנְחָה" ?
The word is always spelled צִיצִת throughout Tanach and not צִיצִית .  (Although this former spelling would contradict Chazal's comment of the gematria of 600.)

I've heard from this site here: [KOL HAMIKRA](http://abaalkoreh.org/tzitzis_trope.php)
that both Chiriks are "Malei" and should be pronounced as a long Chirik sound.

Comment: Why do you assume anything such? Your assumptions may be crucial in answering your question...

Comment: It's a long chirik.  The main clue is the trope/taam position.  Chirik with taam is almost always long.  Short chirik can sometimes take metheg (as a secondary stress), but if the taam is on chirik, then it's long.  The spelling doesn't have any significance grammatically.  For example, the chirik in the name דוד is also long, but the word almost never appears malei in Tanakh.

Answer (score -3):

I think this should answer the question.  The word should be spelled malei on both Tzaddi letters.
[image: I think this may answer it]

Comment: Please remember the site is geared towards English readers. Would be great if you could translate the critical parts of the answer. Having the source is wonderful though but not alone.